# How do I navigate to another page?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router

I take data from the resource thememoviedb. I received a certain number of movies, and I also displayed them on the page. I try to go to each movie to see the details in the file Movie_Details.js. In this file, I get data from the resource as well, but the transition does not occur, and the Movie_Details component is drawn at the bottom. How do I go to the Movie Details page and display the data? Thank you

App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {Popular_Movies} from "./Components/Popular_Movies/Popular_Movies";
import {Movie_Detail} from "./Components/Popular_Movies/Movie_Detail";
function App() {
return (
<div>
    <Router>
            <Popular_Movies/>

            <Route path="/movie/:id" exact>
            <Movie_Detail/>
            </Route>
    </Router>
</div>
);}
export default App;
```

Popular_Movie.js

```
import React from "react";
import {image_api} from "../../Services/Service";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
export let Popular_Movie = ({name, title, poster_path, vote_average}) => {

return (<div className='different_movie'>
    <img src={image_api + poster_path} className='image'/>
    <div className='bottom_different_movie'>
        <h3> <Link to={`/movie/:id`}>{name} {title} {vote_average}</Link></h3>
    </div>
</div>) }
```

Popular_Movies.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Popular_Movie} from "./Popular_Movie";
export let Popular_Movies = () => {
 let popularMovieUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=e12a044061e5fe9077c7aee8a5165126&language=en-US&page=1`;

let fetchMovies = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(popularMovieUrl)
    let data = await response.json()
    setPopularMovie(data.results)
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies()
},[])

return (<div>
{popularMovie.length > 0 && popularMovie.map(movie => <Popular_Movie key={movie.id} {...movie}/>)}
</div>) }
```

Movie_Detail

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export let Movie_Detail = () => {
let movieUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=e12a044061e5fe9077c7aee8a5165126&language=en-US&page=1'
let [differentMovie, setDifferentMovie] = useState([])
let fetchDifferentMovie = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(movieUrl)
    let data = await response.json()
    setDifferentMovie(data.results)
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetchDifferentMovie()
},[])

return (<div>
    {differentMovie.title}
            </div>)}
```

Comment: I think it might be good to remove your API key from your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show movie list on `/` route, and movie details on `/movie/:id` you should have your router structured like this:

```
<Router>
  ... // put navigation component here
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact>
      <Popular_Movies/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/movie/:id" exact>
      <Movie_Detail/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Inside `Movie_Detail` component you need to extract movie `id` by using the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook

```
const { id } = useParams();
... // fetch movie details using `id`
```

It's important for you to understand how `Switch` operates. It's like you have `if-else` logic which shoud decide which component to render when certain path is matched. Please, read more on [Basic Routing](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing).

P.S. The reason you're seeing both popular movies and movie details underneath is because your `Popular_Movies` component call was not wrapped with `<Route>` which means that it should be always present/visible.